# purpose of using base method in derived class

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I'm looking at someone's code and has:

```
protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);  //necessary?
    if (...)
}
```

Now, question is why base class method is called? this code would work without that anyway. any idea?

Thanks.
Amit

Comment: depends on what the base class does. maybe it does nothing. maybe it sets/changes some member variables that are used later in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base calls are used when you want to utilize the functionality of the base's implementation yet want to extend what happens in the derived classes implementation.

This can do some really useful things like setting up properties that are defined in the base class or handling events without having to put boilerplate code in each derived class.

Answer (score 2):

Because the base class method has default behavior that you may still want to take advantage of.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the base class it might be necessary to also execute its method for it to function as intended. It's pretty much convention to call the base code as well as it might be important, especially if you do not know what it does.

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on what you what the event handler to do. If your base class is complicated and it does a lot of things in `OnMouseEnter()` that you still want to keep, then you should have that `base.OnMouseEnter(e)` call. If you want to "override" the function completely, meaning you know what `base.OnMouseEnter(e)` does and you don't want it, then don't call `base.OnMouseEnter(e)`.